# AWS.SimpleDB: How to use API to do putAttributes()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-simpledb

I'm using Amazon Simple DB (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SimpleDB.html)
and I'm trying to use putAttributes by writing the following node.js code:

```
  AWS.config = new AWS.Config({accessKeyId: '***', secretAccessKey: '***', region: '***'});
            var simpledb = new AWS.SimpleDB();
            var params = {
                Attributes: [ 
                    {
                        Name: 'firstname', 
                        Value: 'David' 
                    },
                ],
                DomainName: '***', /* required */
                ItemName: 'per2', /* required */
            };
            simpledb.putAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else     console.log(data);           // successful response
            });
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error in console after reading the line:

```
var simpledb = new AWS.SimpleDB();
```

> try.html?_ijt=no554cohakgtacn421reh33mpr:22 Uncaught TypeError:
>   AWS.SimpleDB is not a constructor

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: did you try to pass an empty object?

Comment: I think that it doesn't even try to pass an object. It fails in the second line of the code way before it reaches the line simpledb.putAttributes(...)

Comment: Now, I tried and I just got the same error.